# gradle custom dependency resolution

Tags: native, gradle, dependency-management

Is it possible to bypass Ivy (or whatever else Gradle uses internally for dependency resolution) and still keep the same dependency DSL? I'm trying to develop a plugin for resolving native dependencies that would use the system's package manager to install dependencies, but Gradle's RepositoryHandler only allows Ivy, Maven, or flat dir repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to completely bypass Gradle's dependency resolution system, then you'll also have to create your own DSL. To do so, you would use Gradle concepts such as "extension objects" and "domain object containers".

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I'd probably have to do that, but I thought it would be worth checking.